# Is it possible to verify the sender origin of an http request using TLS

Tags: http, security, https, cryptography, tls1.2

I have created an API endpoint, I have a user of that endpoint requesting from servers at `stackoverflow.com`. I want to verify that the request was made from `stackoverflow.com` servers. One way I could verify it came from `stackoverflow.com` is to ask the developer to sign the request with their let's encrypt domain private key. I can then use their public key to decrypt the message.

I'm not totally sure I can decrypt the privately encrypted message with their public key but even if I could, I would like to avoid having the developer do any special type of encryption. Could I use TLS to verify the origin domain?

Comment: how much control do you have over the client making the request?  i.e. why not just have it pass a header containing some key/password that you can check

Comment: A properly implemented TLS client will always authenticate the server, so yes, successfully completing the handshake will give you and encrypted **and** authenticated connection, unless you are intentionally going out of your way to use a non-authenticating ciphersuite.

Comment: @JamesKPolk AFIK TLS normally authenticates the origin server is who it claims rather than the requesting node. For example a browser authenticates the origin it is making requests to. In this scenario I want to authenticate the client making the request is who it says it is.

Comment: @SamMason I do plan on also using a secret but having let's encrypt to verify signatures would be a beneficial extra layer of security

Comment: That seems to be exactly the opposite of what you said in your question.

Comment: lets encrypt is just a way of getting a key pair from a "well known" CA.  what you do with that key afterwards is up to you.  I fail to see how it would provide an "extra layer of security" here and might make things worse as more code would need access to a private key that could be used to impersonate the web server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TLS supports client authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Client-authenticated_TLS_handshake), also called '2-way' or 'mutual' authentication. (SSL3 also did, but you should not be using SSL3.) See e.g. [TLS1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.4)
'updated' for [ECC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4492#section-5.5) and [TLS1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-4.3.2).

How to use this depends on the software (typically library or middleware) being used for TLS, which you didn't indicate; it is even possible some TLS stack doesn't support it at all, though I've never heard of any. *Some* stacks or use-cases allow client auth to be invoked without any code change, and others with only minimal or localized code change.

Some details that may or may not matter:

- this does not sign the *request*. It authenticates the TLS *connection* (to be exact, it normally signs a transcript of the handshake) and then the data transferred over the connection is MACed (as well as encrypted) using keys created (and thus authenticated) by the handshake. This provides authentication but not nonrepudiation for the data; *you* the receiver can reliably determine it came from the sender, but you can't reliably prove this to a third party. For the closely related case of 'proving' the *server*, see the numerous crossdupes linked at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/205074/is-it-possible-to-save-a-verifiable-log-of-a-tls-session .
- this authenticates the data was *sent* by the identified client; it says nothing about the *origin* which as Sam Jason points out is often different.
- the client is not necessarily identified by a domain name; it can be a person, organization, or something else. However, *many* CAs issue a single cert for both TLS server auth *and* client auth (look at the ExtendedKeyUsage extension in your own or any sample cert(s) to see) and in that case with few exceptions the subject is identified by a domain name or name(s) or at least wildcard(s).

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you should be using some sort of API key or maybe something similar to how [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security#validating-requests) signs its requests

one reason for these patterns is that it's common for HTTP requests to be proxied, with static requests handled by something other than the code/application server.  therefore the TLS connection would have been terminated at the proxy server, and the actual application code wouldn't be able to easily see anything about the TLS connection used by the remote server